# Selenium find text between header and footer tag

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.sap.com/about/events/2021-05-25-online-pe-payment-processing-sap.html')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
print(element.text)
driver.close()

<html>
<head>
<body>
<div>
<header>....<\header>
<main>
<div>
<header> ... <\header>
...
...
...
<footer>...<\footer>
```

Is there a solution using selenium python to get text from main by removing the text from 1st header and below footer. I cannot use xpath for main tag because it vary in multiple websites.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead : `(Use of split())`

```
driver.get("https://www.sap.com/about/events/2021-05-25-online-pe-payment-processing-sap.html")
element = driver.page_source
remove_header = element.split("</header>")
remove_header_footer = remove_header[1].split("<footer>")
print(remove_header_footer[0])
```

First I am splitting entire page source with `</header>` and storing that in a `remove_header`. Now `remove_header[1]` will have page source without header again split using `<footer>` and the remaining string is now without `header` and `footer`

Comment: I have updated the above code, let me know if it works for you

Comment: So after removing header and footer how to get the text only from <main> tag. The element variable you have written is driver.page_source.It retrieves entire page source not the text.

Comment: You cant get text from driver.page _source

Comment: from selenium import webdriver

# Chrome Path
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.sap.com/about/events/2021-05-25-online-pe-payment-processing-sap.html")
element = driver.page_source
remove_header = element.split("</header>")
remove_header_footer = remove_header[1].split("<footer>")
a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
print(a.text)

Comment: From above code I need to get the text only

Comment: try this then `print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body").text)`

Comment: What do you mean by main ?

Comment: Main is the <main> tag from the HTML . I am trying to get the entire text inside main tag by remove header and footer tag text

Comment: I have given you one solution in one of your newer post

Comment: From driver.page_source you will get entire html elements. But how to get text after removing footer and header tag For eg:  I need to get the text only hello  <header>.....<\header>   ----> Remove text
<main>
<div>
<header> ... <\header>
<p> Hello </p>
...
...
<footer>...<\footer>   ----> Remove text

Comment: I tried this `print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html[not(contains(@id, 'header')) and not(contains(@id, 'footer'))]").text)` give me quite good output